# Add 3 rows separately at the end of the crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crosstab

I am working on crosstab in Crystal Reports, I am able to see required data and everything is fine but I am stuck at one point where I need to insert `Total`, `Avg` and `Max` as 3 rows one below one at the end of cross tab.

I have tried `Embedded Summary` but that one is inserting a row below every row of the cross tab but I don't need that way.

[image: Image of my problem]

I searched the web, but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Did you tried with Summary fields?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sivaraman.. but this is a cross tab how can I use summary fields here.. can you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.:

1. In preview mode added the rows using the option `Calculated Summary`, by this way we can add any number of rows at the end of the cross tab.
2. Now by editing the required row, added the calculation formula for `Sum`, `Max` and `Average`.

Answer (score 0):

Have Global variables Like below:
Shared integer TotalCol1 CurrentVers; 
Shared integer MaxCol1;

In the details section, use a formula to calculate these variables. (Max, Sum, Avg should be computed. Max may required a condition check before replace the present global value).

At the end, you can print these variables using a formula in the Footer (Group or report that you can decide)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but I am using crosstab and I want to show below as rows in crosstab. How can I achive that?